# Why is my MySQL query returning a multidimensional array rather than a single-dimension array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, web-applications

This is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ap.apptype_id
FROM tblSubmission AS s
JOIN tblApp AS ap ON ap.app_id = s.app_id
WHERE s.app_id =406
OR s.app_id =180
OR s.app_id =179
```

It returns just unique apptype_ids pertaining to rows in a database. It works right now like it should, except for the fact that it returns a multidimensional array, rather than a single-dimension array. I could go ahead and write a PHP function that resolves this, but I would rather have the query return the array properly rather than make the server do extra work to fix the problem with the query. Can anyone help me out?

Also, if anyone sees a way I can optimize this query to make it even quicker, that would be great as well!

```
function db_query($querystring) { 
   $rec_set = array(); 
   $result = mysql_query($querystring); 
   if (!$result) { 
       // do nothing, query might have failed but it might have just returned no results          
       #echo ("Invalid Query Result:<br /><b>" . $querystring . "</b><br />"); // debug 
    }elseif($result === true){ 
       // do nothing, query didn't return anything but succeeded 
    }else{ 
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { $rec_set[] = $row; }            
       mysql_free_result($result); 
    } 
    return $rec_set; 
  }
```

Comment: How are you fetching it? That should return a resource, if called from `mysql_query`.

Comment: can you show an example of the array it is returning, since I think that is more a function of what you are using to query the DB, not the query itself.

Comment: Interpretation of SQL results, as far as I know, depends on the php side. Where's php code?

Comment: That's just how queries work. It will return each successful select as a row so it will return an array of rows, each row holding an array of values. In this case, the data is just a single value (the id).

Comment: This is the array that is returned from the query: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [apptype_id] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [apptype_id] => 7
        )

)

Comment: show the php code that fetches the result, since that is what is coercing it into the array or arrays result.

Comment: `function db_query($querystring)
{
 $rec_set = array();

 $result = mysql_query($querystring);
 if (!$result)
 {
  // do nothing, query might have failed but it might have just returned no results
  #echo ("Invalid Query Result:<br /><b>" . $querystring . "</b><br />"); // debug
 } elseif ($result === true) {
  // do nothing, query didn't return anything but succeeded
 } else {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
   $rec_set[] = $row;
  }
  mysql_free_result($result);
 }
 return $rec_set;
}`

Sorry that's formatted strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning two records so it's multidimensional.

You have `DISTINCT ap.apptype_id` and your query finds two records with distinct ids.

EDIT: just to clarify; in a single dimensional array as you'd look for I believe the result you intended was:

```
array([7], [2]) // i.e your two distinct ids.
```

Try to remember that with mysql you get returned the column header too so this layout wouldn't make sense.

EDIT 2:

Maybe something like this would help?

```
$a = array(
    0 => array('first'=>7),
    1 => array('second'=>2)
);

$row = array_map('implode', $a);
```

OUTPUT:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "7" [1]=> string(1) "2" }
```

The array_map is the function you'd want here. It should work as you need.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know the column header would be returned as well. And yes, the `array([7], [2])` is what I am trying to get. I assume there is no way to strip the column header?

Comment: EDIT: Moved into main answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ap.apptype_id
FROM tblSubmission AS s
JOIN tblApp AS ap ON ap.app_id = s.app_id
```

Above part will select all distinct `apptype_id` for which `app_id` is both in `tblSubmission` and `tblApp`. And then you are taking if ID is either `406 OR 180 OR 179`. So it will return all `apptype_id` for which corresponding `ID`s match with these three `ID`s and are in both tables.

Suppose,

`tblApp(id, type)` has three entries `<406, 10>`, `<180, 11>` and `<100, 12>`. 
`tblSubmission(id, ...)` has three entries `<406, ...>`, `<180, ...>` and `<179, ...>`.
after joining `table(id, type, ...)` will have two entries 
`<406, 10, ...>` and `<180, 11, ...>`
just think what will happen if you select distinct type? it will return two entries 
`<10>` and `<11>`

Answer (score 0):

It is returning the multi-dimensional array because you are asking it to with  `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`

If you move your code to something like PDO you can use fetch column to grab what you want.   http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php

In regards to your original question, the query is fine, the way you are fetching it from PHP is what is causing the issue.   As for making it faster you might consider using `IN` as opposed opposed to the multiple `ORs` but I am not sure if that would make any difference with mysql (you can use EXPLAIN on the query to show what the DB is using to get the results)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, I am not able to switch to PDO at the moment (maybe next year when the application is re-written). I'll just use PHP to flatten the array out instead. Once again, thank you!